# Angular Jasmine Test not working by ngOninit Test

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine, angular-test

I write a jasmine test for my angular application. But I got an error on ngOninit()

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cStations' of undefined
```

my code looks like this: -

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.sResult.cStations) {
      this.cStations = this.sResult.cStations;
    } else if (this.sResult.rs) {
      this.cStations = this.sResult.rs.length > 0 ? this.sResult.rs[0].cStations : undefined;
    }
  }
```

and my unit test looks like this:-

```
describe('BarChartHorizontalComponent', () => {
  let component: BarChartHorizontalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BarChartHorizontalComponent>;
  let cStations: CStation;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ BarChartHorizontalComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BarChartHorizontalComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.cStations = [];
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });

  it('should have input value', () => {
    expect(component.cStations).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

the question is how can I define or init properties in test for ngOninit function

any solutions??

Comment: can you show the code of the unit test?

Comment: i have added uni test

Comment: What and where is property `xxxx`

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 component.cStations = [];
```

with

```
 component.sResult = {cStations: []};
```